# Apps Script : Bad value error for displaying google sheet as web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to display google sheet as a web app but returned a bad value error when trying to run it.

Here is the *Code.gs*:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
 

function getData(){
  var spreadSheetId = "    "; //I have entered correct sheet id
  var dataRange     = "Sheet1!A2:H";
 
  var range   = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId,dataRange);
  var values  = range.values;
 
  return values;
}
 

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

This is the *Index.html* code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
 
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?> 
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
          <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

*JavaScript.html* code:

```
<script>
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
  
  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
      
        columns: [
          {"title":"File Name"},
          {"title":"Description"},
          {"title":"File Type"},
          {"title":"Category"},
          {"title":"File Extension"},
          {"title":"File Link"}
          {"title":"Uploaded By"},
          {"title":"Upload Date"},
        ]
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

The error is in line 18, when I tried to run the **include** function in *Code.gs* (showed in this screen shot) [image])

I'm not sure what went wrong, anyone has an idea?

Comment: Please provide `Index.html`.  An `include` in that template is causing the error.

Comment: I have included the Index.html code above, any idea what went wrong?

Comment: showData() function not provided

Comment: The showData() function is in JavaScript.html code (I just added the code in my original question). Maybe it'll more clear for you to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question of `I'm trying to display google sheet as a web app but returned a bad value error when trying to run it.` and `I'm not sure what went wrong, anyone has an idea?`, how about the following modification points?

#### Modification points:

- About your current error of `Exception: Bad value`, in this case, when the function `include` is directly run with the script editor, such an error occurs, because of no value of `filename`. I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to this.
- In your script, it seems that you wanted to load "JavaScript" file when the HTML is loaded. So, in this case, please open your Web Apps with your browser. By this, the HTML template is loaded by replacing `<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>` with your Javascript using `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();`.

#### Note:

- When I put a sample "JavaScript" file and I tested your showing script by opening Web Apps with my browser, no error occurs.
- I guess that the script calling `getData()` might be included in "JavaScript", and also, I suppose that you have already confirmed that `<!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->` worked. If you have an issue with this part, please provide the detail of it.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

### Added:

About your following reply,

> It's still doesn't work. I just added the JavaScript.html code in my original question, probably more clearer for you to know what cause the error

When I saw your added Javascript, I think that your Javascript has a modification point. About the following part,

```js
columns: [
  {"title":"File Name"},
  {"title":"Description"},
  {"title":"File Type"},
  {"title":"Category"},
  {"title":"File Extension"},
  {"title":"File Link"} // <--- , is required to be added.
  {"title":"Uploaded By"},
  {"title":"Upload Date"},
]
```

When this is reflected in your whole script, it becomes as follows.

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  var spreadSheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
  var dataRange = "Sheet1!A2:H";
  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;
  return values;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

#### HTML: `Index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
 
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?> 
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
          <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript: `JavaScript.html`

```html
<script>
  
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();

function showData(dataArray) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
      data: dataArray,

      columns: [
        { "title": "File Name" },
        { "title": "Description" },
        { "title": "File Type" },
        { "title": "Category" },
        { "title": "File Extension" },
        { "title": "File Link" },
        { "title": "Uploaded By" },
        { "title": "Upload Date" },
      ]
    });
  });
}

</script>
```

- When I tested the above Google Apps Script, HTML, and Javascript, no error occurs. I confirmed that a table is shown in the browser. So, please correctly copy and paste the above and test it.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: It's still doesn't work. I just added the JavaScript.html code in my original question, probably more clearer for you to know what cause the error

Comment: @Jack Thank you for replying. About `It's still doesn't work. I just added the JavaScript.html code in my original question, probably more clearer for you to know what cause the error`, I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that your added Javascript has a modification point. So, I added the whole modified script. Please confirm it. In that case, please don't directly run the function `include`. Please reflect the latest script to Web Apps and test it with your browser. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Jack If the situation of `It's still doesn't work.` occurred again, please provide a sample Spreadsheet including the current script for correctly replicating the issue. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

GS:

```
function getMyData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ss.getId(),"Sheet1!A1:H" + sh.getLastRow()).values
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
  return vs;
}

function launchMyDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah1').evaluate(),'Dialog')
}
```

html ah1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tabledata">
       <? var vs = getMyData(); ?>
       <table>
         <? vs.forEach((r,i)=>{ ?>
           <tr>
           <? r.forEach((c,j)=>{ ?>
             <? if(i == 0) { ?>
            <th style="padding:2px 5px;font-weight:bold;border:1px solid black;"><?= c ?> </th>           
           <? } else { ?>
             <td style="padding:2px 5px;border:1px solid black;"><?= vs[i][j] ?> </td>
           <? } ?>
         <?  }); ?>
           </tr>
         <? }); ?>
       </table>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]